# How to modify list-indexes according to a list which contains only the changed indexes?

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, sorting

**Update**: Here is the complete code https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAeWp5

This one is much more difficult than i thought. 
In the real project i need to update a database table which has a column `Position`(for the sort-order), but all the method gets is a list that contains only the changed objects with the new positions. The table and class is `WatchList`.

Here it is:

```
public class WatchList : IEquatable<WatchList>
{
    public WatchList(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(WatchList other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        WatchList other = obj as WatchList;
        return this.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"WatchListId:{Id} Name:{Name} UserId:{UserId} Position:{Position}";
    }
}
```

So the `WatchListId` is the primary key and the `Position` the column that i want to update.

Consider that this table contains following WatchLists:

```
WatchListId   Position
1             1
2             2
3             3
4             4
5             5
```

The user wants to modify the order, drags and drops them and finally submits it to the server. The client will call `UpdateWatchListsSort` with a list that contains only the WatchLists that were moved by the user.

Consider the user moved

```
1   --->   5
3   --->   1
5   --->   4
```

So the new (correct) order in the database was:

```
WatchListId   Position
3             1
2             2
4             3
5             4
1             5
```

You notice that even some other WatchLists must be updated because the positions need to move up by 1 if their positions are affected. This is were it gets tricky. All items that are not moved to a position should keep a stable order (by `Position`). In this case ID=2 and ID=4 should stay in this order.

The sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var changedWatchLists = new List<WatchList>
        {
            new WatchList(1) {Position = 5}, new WatchList(3) {Position = 1}, new WatchList(5) {Position = 4}
        };
        WatchList.UpdateWatchListsSort("123", changedWatchLists);
    }
}
```

My approach is to load first the complete `List<WatchList>`(from DB) and then merge it with the passed list with the new Positions. This enables to validate the input before and should make it simpler because all can be done in memory.

The basic logic is to `Remove` all changed `WatchLists` from the complete list and then `Insert` it at the desired position.

I enumerate only the change-list ordered by the new position to avoid side-affects. Otherwise `List.Insert` could move up items that had already the target position.

However, at the end **i still have items which are at the wrong position**, so i'm stuck.

The complete method `UpdateWatchListsSort`:

```
public static void UpdateWatchListsSort(string userId, List<WatchList> watchListsWithModifiedPosition)
{
    List<WatchList> allUserWatchLists = GetWatchListsFromDb(userId);
    // mapping WatchListId --> WatchList (from DB)
    Dictionary<int, WatchList> dbWatchListIdLookup = allUserWatchLists.ToDictionary(w => w.Id);

    if (watchListsWithModifiedPosition.Count == allUserWatchLists.Count)
        allUserWatchLists = watchListsWithModifiedPosition;
    else
    {
        // enumerate all modified WatchLists ordered by position ascending (to avoid side affects)
        foreach (WatchList modified in watchListsWithModifiedPosition.OrderBy(w => w.Position))
        {
            WatchList dbWatchList = dbWatchListIdLookup[modified.Id];
            int newIndex = modified.Position - 1;
            int oldIndex = allUserWatchLists.IndexOf(dbWatchList); // might be at a different position meanwhile( != db-position )
            allUserWatchLists.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
            // if moved forwards index is index-1 because the watchlist was already removed at List.RemoveAt, 
            // if moved backwards index isn't affected
            bool movedForwards = newIndex > oldIndex;
            if (movedForwards)
                newIndex--;
            allUserWatchLists.Insert(newIndex, dbWatchList);
        }
    }

    var changeInfos = allUserWatchLists
        .Select((wl, index) => new { WatchList = wl, NewPosition = index + 1 })
        .Where(x => x.WatchList.Position != x.NewPosition)
        .ToList();
    foreach (var change in changeInfos)
    {
        WatchList wl = change.WatchList;
        wl.Position = change.NewPosition;
        // check if the new position is equal to the position given as parameter
        Debug.Assert(wl.Position == watchListsWithModifiedPosition
           .Where(w => w.Id == wl.Id)
           .Select(w => w.Position)
           .DefaultIfEmpty(wl.Position)
           .First());
    }
    // check if allUserWatchLists contains duplicate Positions which is invalid
    Debug.Assert(allUserWatchLists
       .Select(w => w.Position)
       .Distinct().Count() == allUserWatchLists.Count);

    // update changeInfos.Select(x => x.WatchList) via table-valued-parameter in DB (not related) .....
}

private static List<WatchList> GetWatchListsFromDb(string userId)
{
    var allDbWatchLists = new List<WatchList>
    {
        new WatchList(1) {Position = 1}, new WatchList(2) {Position = 2}, new WatchList(3) {Position = 3},
        new WatchList(4) {Position = 4}, new WatchList(5) {Position = 5}
    };
    return allDbWatchLists;
}
```

If you execute this sample this `Debug.Assert` will fail:

```
// check if the new position is equal to the position given as parameter
Debug.Assert(wl.Position == watchListsWithModifiedPosition
    .Where(w => w.Id == wl.Id)
    .Select(w => w.Position)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(wl.Position)
    .First());
```

So the algorithm is wrong because a `WatchList` new `Position` is not the desired one (given as parameter).

I hope you understand this requirement and see what i'm doing wrong. I suspect this part but don't know how to fix it:

```
 // if moved forwards index is index-1 because the watchlist was already removed at List.RemoveAt, 
// if moved backwards index isn't affected
bool movedForwards = newIndex > oldIndex;
if (movedForwards)
    newIndex--;
```

Maybe you have even a better approach, readability is important.

Comment: Just to be clear:  you get the list of operations that the user actually performed, in the order that he performed them?  For example if you have IDs [1000,2000] in the table, and you get [ 2000->1, 1000->1], then the table should remain unchanged?

Comment: @MattTimmermans: i get a list of `WatchList` that contains only those which positions were changed but without those which were affected (f.e. a WatchList changed from 2->1, so  WatchList 1 must move up to 2, in this case i get only `WatchList ID=2 Position=1`). This is to reduce network traffic. Otherwise you have to pass all WatchLists (it could be 10000) if you move the last to the first position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an insertion sort algorithm principle. The steps of the algorithm are:

1. Get a list of original objects (`original`) and input ones (`input`)
2. Throw away all objects in `original` that are in `input`. Order the rest by `Position` field. Call this new list `ordered`
3. For each object in input find the place to put it in the `ordered` and place it there

In the end you would get a list of objects which is correctly ordered, but positions are out of date. But position now corresponds to the index of the object in `ordered` list, so this is easy to fix.

Code to illustrate what I mean. I did a bit of simplification of definitions to make is short:

```
class WatchList
{
    public int WatchListId;
    public int Position;
}

List<WatchList> original = new List<WatchList>
{
    new WatchList{WatchListId=1, Position=1},
    new WatchList{WatchListId=2, Position=2},
    new WatchList{WatchListId=3, Position=3},
    new WatchList{WatchListId=4, Position=4},
    new WatchList{WatchListId=5, Position=5}
};

List<WatchList> input = new List<WatchList>
{
    new WatchList{WatchListId=1, Position=5},
    new WatchList{WatchListId=3, Position=1},
    new WatchList{WatchListId=5, Position=4}
};
```

And now the algo goes like this:

```
List<WatchList> ordered = original.Where(w => !input.Any(iw => iw.WatchListId == w.WatchListId)).OrderBy(w => w.Position).ToList();
foreach (var inputWatchlist in input)
{
    int indexToInsert = 0;
    while (indexToInsert < ordered.Count)
    {
        if (ordered[indexToInsert].Position <= inputWatchlist.Position)
        {
            indexToInsert++;
        } 
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    ordered.Insert(indexToInsert, inputWatchlist);
}
```

This outputs

```
foreach (var w in ordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: " + w.WatchListId + " P: " + w.Position);
}

Id: 3 P: 1
Id: 2 P: 2
Id: 4 P: 4
Id: 5 P: 4
Id: 1 P: 5
```

Link to sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7MtjVZ

As you can see objects are ordered as expected, positions are out of place. However updating positions is now trivial.

Comment: This misses the main difficulty, the new positions affect the positions of the original-list. So if i move one item from 3 to 1, the item 1 is also affected because it must move up to 2(if that positons is not already occupied by another that wants to be moved to 2). The extreme example: you move the last item to the first position. The input-list contains only this single item, but all others are affected too because they must move up. This move-up operation can also affect items that were already at the desired position which is why i orderd by Position first.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, i do not think it misses that. Note that we actually do not worry about what is in `Position` field much, because in `ordered` list the index of the item is its position. That is once `ordered` is completed position of `item ordered[i]` is `i`. So, if all items had to move up - they will move up, and in the end we recalc their positions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, as for ordering by position first - fair point, i did have this in the code but forgot to mention in the description. Updated

Comment: Thanks Andrei. It's indeed much simpler to first remove all changed watchlists from the complete list to avoid that you have to remove them in the loop which causes poistion changes on others.

Comment: However, i'm currently using the second version of [Matt Timmermans approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40285724/284240)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm almost works, but you need to remove all the old watch lists first, and *then* reinsert them at their new positions.

The way it's currently written, you can remove a dbWatchList from position 1 *after* inserting a new one at position 2, and that will change the position of the inserted watch list.

The corrected function looks like this:

```
public static void UpdateWatchListsSort(string userId, List<WatchList> watchListsWithModifiedPosition)
{
    var modifiedIds = new HashSet<int>(watchListsWithModifiedPosition.Select( w=>w.Id ));

    List<WatchList> allUserWatchLists = GetWatchListsFromDb(userId);

    var modifiedWatchLists = allUserWatchLists.FindAll(w => modifiedIds.Contains(w.Id)).ToDictionary(w => w.Id);

    allUserWatchLists.RemoveAll( w => modifiedIds.Contains(w.Id));

    foreach (WatchList modified in watchListsWithModifiedPosition.OrderBy(w => w.Position))
    {
        int newIndex = modified.Position - 1;
        allUserWatchLists.Insert(newIndex, modifiedWatchLists[modified.Id]);
    }

    //... Your testing and Position fix-up code ...
}
```

Note, however that the above is an O(N^2) algorithm, since it inserts into the middle of a list.  It's actually much faster to make a new list like this:

```
public static void UpdateWatchListsSort(string userId, List<WatchList> watchListsWithModifiedPosition)
{
    var modifiedIds = new HashSet<int>(watchListsWithModifiedPosition.Select( w=>w.Id ));

    List<WatchList> allUserWatchLists = GetWatchListsFromDb(userId);

    var modifiedWatchLists = allUserWatchLists.FindAll(w => modifiedIds.Contains(w.Id)).ToDictionary(w => w.Id);

    var newList = new List<WatchList>();
    var unmodifiedIter = allUserWatchLists.FindAll(w => !modifiedIds.Contains(w.Id)).GetEnumerator();

    foreach (WatchList modified in watchListsWithModifiedPosition.OrderBy(w => w.Position))
    {
        int newIndex = modified.Position - 1;
        while(newList.Count < newIndex && unmodifiedIter.MoveNext())
            newList.Add(unmodifiedIter.Current);

        newList.Add(modifiedWatchLists[modified.Id]);
    }
    while(unmodifiedIter.MoveNext())
        newList.Add(unmodifiedIter.Current);

    allUserWatchLists = newList;

    //... Your testing and Position fix-up code ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand. The `foreach` _does_ remove the `WatchList` first before it inserts it at the target index: `allUserWatchLists.RemoveAt(oldIndex);`. Note that i don't add new watchlists. The `List<WatchList>` passed as parameter is a subset of `allUserWatchLists`. I've added the code at [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAeWp5) (without assertions but console.output)

Comment: @TimSchmelter you have to remove ALL the watch lists from their old positions before doing any inserts.  *Then* you can insert them into their new positions, confident that they won't be moved.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added the corrected function to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't checked it yet but i think it's working. It's the same algorithm as Andreis, isn't it? You're right, my initial attempt failed because the Remove during enumeration also changes the list.

Comment: Thanks again, i'll accept Andreis anyway because he was the first who mentioned that i should remove all changed WatchLists first before i'm going to insert them into their correct positions. But i'll use your second approach :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is indeed much difficult - my initial attempt was totally wrong.

Here is my second attempt - IMO a quite efficient algorithm based on modified merge of two ordered sequences (commented in the code):

```
public static void UpdateWatchListsSort(string userId, List<WatchList> watchListsWithModifiedPosition)
{
    // Get the original ordered sequence
    var oldSeq = GetWatchListsFromDb(userId);
    // Create sequence with elements to be modified (ordered by the new position)
    var modifiedSeq = watchListsWithModifiedPosition.OrderBy(e => e.Position);
    // Extract ordered sequence with the remaining elements (ordered by the original position) 
    var otherSeq = oldSeq.Except(watchListsWithModifiedPosition);
    // Build the new ordered sequence by merging the two 
    var newSeq = new List<WatchList>(oldSeq.Count);
    using (var modifiedIt = modifiedSeq.GetEnumerator())
    using (var otherIt = otherSeq.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var modified = modifiedIt.MoveNext() ? modifiedIt.Current : null;
        var other = otherIt.MoveNext() ? otherIt.Current : null;
        while (modified != null || other != null)
        {
            if (modified != null && modified.Position == newSeq.Count + 1)
            {
                newSeq.Add(modified);
                modified = modifiedIt.MoveNext() ? modifiedIt.Current : null;
            }
            else
            {
                newSeq.Add(other);
                other = otherIt.MoveNext() ? otherIt.Current : null;
            }
        }
    }
    // Here the new sequence elements are in the correct order
    // Update the Position field and populate a list 
    // with the items that need db update
    var updateList = new List<WatchList>();
    for (int i = 0; i < newSeq.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = newSeq[i];
        if (item.Id == oldSeq[i].Id) continue;
        item.Position = i + 1;
        updateList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

or the more compact version using LINQ `Zip`:

```
public static void UpdateWatchListsSort(string userId, List<WatchList> watchListsWithModifiedPosition)
{
    // Get the original ordered sequence
    var oldSeq = GetWatchListsFromDb(userId);
    // Build the new ordered sequence
    var newSeq = new WatchList[oldSeq.Count];
    // Place the modified elements in their new position
    foreach (var item in watchListsWithModifiedPosition)
        newSeq[item.Position - 1] = item;
    // Place the remaining elements in the free slots, keeping the original order
    var remainingSeq = Enumerable.Range(0, newSeq.Length)
        .Where(index => newSeq[index] == null)
        .Zip(oldSeq.Except(watchListsWithModifiedPosition), (index, item) => new { index, item });
    foreach (var entry in remainingSeq)
        newSeq[entry.index] = entry.item;
    // Update the Position field and populate a list with the items that need db update
    var updateList = new List<WatchList>();
    for (int i = 0; i < newSeq.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = newSeq[i];
        if (item.Id == oldSeq[i].Id) continue;
        item.Position = i + 1;
        updateList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Finally, I've ended up with a simple LINQ:

```
public static void UpdateWatchListsSortB(string userId, List<WatchList> modifiedList)
{
    var originalList = GetWatchListsFromDb(userId);
    var updateList = modifiedList
        .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, originalList.Count).Except(modifiedList.Select(e => e.Position))
        .Zip(originalList.Except(modifiedList), (pos, e) => e.Position == pos ? e : new WatchList(e.Id) { Position = pos }))
        .Where(e => e.Id != originalList[e.Position - 1].Id)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Since my head is already spinning i'll have a look at it later or tomorrow. The initial sort is not needed because it's already sorted by Position via `ORDER BY`. The approach from Andrei seems to work already.

Comment: @TimSchmelter *my head is already spinning* - no way, I can't believe that :)

Comment: However, it needs some rework because a quick test with a different sample returned wrong positions in the itemList. Need to look at it. I think there is an issue if the `watchListsWithModifiedPosition` is not ordered by position(which is a normal case). First tested with: `new WatchList(4) {Position = 5}, new WatchList(2) {Position = 1}, new WatchList(1) {Position = 4}`

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your efforts. I'll accept Andrei's which was first who mentioned the approach to simply remove all which were changed from the complete-list first. Then the insertion is much easier because you avoid the issue of changing posititions if you remove them in the loop. Matt Timmermann used a similar approach.

Comment: You are welcome @Tim, it was interesting challenge. No problem with accepting Andrei's answer, but I would recommend you using my second approach which is O(N) while Andrei's is O(N*M) and really performs slow when M is relatively big (probably not a typical case). Cheers.

Comment: Ok, actually i'm using [Matt Timmermans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40285724/284240) second version

Comment: For some reason can't stop thinking of it :) Ended up with LINQ, now I feel satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge a week or so ago relating to priorities in a gridview. The algorithm that eventually worked for me is the following:

```
      foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvSerials.Rows)
            {
                //Moved record up
                if (Priority < e.RowIndex + 1)
                {
                    //Greater than priority but less than index - Increase Prioirty
                    if (gvr.RowIndex + 1 >= Priority && gvr.RowIndex < e.RowIndex)
                        DAL.UpdatePriority(gvr.RowIndex + 2, int.Parse(gvSerials.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["SerialID"].ToString()));
                }
                else if (Priority > e.RowIndex + 1)
                {
                    if (gvr.RowIndex > e.RowIndex)
                    {
                        if (gvr.RowIndex + 1 <= Priority)
                            DAL.UpdatePriority(gvr.RowIndex, int.Parse(gvSerials.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["SerialID"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
```

I decided to rather have the users move the priority orders and then make the changes to the database after the submit and not try to maintain a list of changes, and only commit the entire list at the end.

I used the rowindex of the row in conjunction with the priority to get the desired result.

I dont for a second believe the way I did it is the correct or most efficient way but maybe it leads you to think of something you had not thought of yet.

Comment: Thanks. But i don't think that it can help me because it's a different requirement. I have a list which contains only new positions(f.e. the user drags&drops an item from 3 to 1). But this action affectes more items(in this example all items between 1 and 3 which must move up by 1). These changes are not in the list and must be calculated without destroying the positions given as parameter. So the target list contains only the changes, but the complete list which includes the affected items.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are saying, with the limited information that you are working with in that method, you need to do a cascading set of fetches. First fetch to get the existing holders of the positions, so that when you swap out, you can assign the original holders to new positions.

Then you have to fetch the next set of affected position holders, and repeat this process. Essentially, this is going to become a bubble-sort kind of a thing. Not very performant, unfortunately, because of all the roundtrips required to the back-end.

An alternative approach would be to hold all the positions in memory, and skip the roundtripping. You still need to iterate through all the affected positions, but since you have the entire list unfolded in memory, you can skip the roundtripping. Still constrained to a bubble-sort kind of computations, IMHO.

Comment: It would be great if you could try to modify the [sample code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAeWp5) to provide an example. My approach already loads all into memory(not an issue and required to validate the input(omitted above). But it's still difficult to find all affected items and to update them with the corect new Position. Note that the Position is basically the list-index +1. So if the list is correctly ordered, all WatchLists are at the correct position and i have the correct result.